# Moving up a Grid according to Coin Flips

Tags: probability

> Imagine that you are at $(0, 0)$ on a lattice grid, and your goal is
>   to reach $(4, 4)$. At each time step, you flip an unfair coin that comes up heads with probability $p$.
>   If you flip a heads you move up one unit; otherwise, you
>   move right one unit. What is the probability that you will reach the
>   point $(4, 4)$?
>
> Now imagine that I give you the option of re-flipping the coin exactly
>   once during this game. For example, if you flip a heads, and you are not happy with this flip, you may choose to
>   re-flip the coin. Note that you may end up having to move up one unit anyways if you flip a heads on the re-roll. What is the optimal strategy for deciding when to use your re-flip, given that your goal is still to reach $(4, 4)$?

The first part of this question is quite straightforward, but I'm a bit stuck on figuring out an optimal strategy. One thought I have is to use the re-flip only when you have to, i.e. if you're at the point $(2, 4)$ and you flip a heads which will prevent you from ever reaching $(4, 4)$.

However, I've also thought of the following scenario, assuming $p > \frac{1}{2}$. If you're at the point $(0, 3)$ and you flip a heads, it's quite unlikely that you will flip $4$ tails in a row. Therefore, it might be better to try to re-flip and get to $(1, 3)$ on the current turn. That being said, there's the possibility that you flip a heads on the re-flip and "waste" your re-flip.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your title says dice rolls but the body talks of coin flips

Answer (score 1):

I would claim that you should only re-flip when it is necessary.  With that strategy you win any time the first $9$ flips (including an extra one if you get to $(4,4)$ without a re-flip) come out $5$ of one face and $4$ of the other.  If you reflip from $(0,3)$ when you get heads you will lose $HHH(H)TTTTT$ where the wait until you need it wins.  Any other strategy will cause you to lose some games you would have won because you replace a side you needed with one that you don't.